# Seaborn bar graph after group by to create top N x label in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to create a seaborn bar graph, problem is before creating the bar graph I need to create database based on column value(descending). For further explanation below is the data type

| City | Complaint Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ARVERNE | Blocked Driveway | 50 |
| ARVERNE | Derelict Vehicle | 32 |
| ARVERNE | Disorderly Youth | 2 |
| ARVERNE | Drinking | 1 |
| ASTORIA | Animal Abuse | 170 |
| ASTORIA | Bike/Roller/Skate Chronic | 16 |
| ASTORIA | Blocked Driveway | 3436 |
| ASTORIA | Derelict Vehicle | 426 |
| BAYSIDE | Animal Abuse | 53 |
| BAYSIDE | Blocked Driveway | 514 |
| BAYSIDE | Derelict Vehicle | 231 |
| BAYSIDE | Disorderly Youth | 2 |
| BELLEROSE | Animal Abuse | 15 |
| BELLEROSE | Bike/Roller/Skate Chronic | 1 |
| BELLEROSE | Blocked Driveway | 138 |
| BELLEROSE | Derelict Vehicle | 120 |
| BREEZY POINT | Animal Abuse | 2 |
| BREEZY POINT | Blocked Driveway | 3 |
| BREEZY POINT | Derelict Vehicle | 3 |
| BREEZY POINT | Illegal Parking | 16 |

Now I want to create graph with top 3 city with complaint and there major complain type, so if I use top 2 complain type then my data should look like the below

| City | Complaint Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ASTORIA | Blocked Driveway | 3436 |
| ASTORIA | Derelict Vehicle | 426 |
| BAYSIDE | Blocked Driveway | 514 |
| BAYSIDE | Derelict Vehicle | 231 |
| BELLEROSE | Blocked Driveway | 138 |
| BELLEROSE | Derelict Vehicle | 120 |
| ARVERNE | Blocked Driveway | 50 |
| ARVERNE | Derelict Vehicle | 32 |
| BREEZY POINT | Illegal Parking | 16 |
| BREEZY POINT | Derelict Vehicle | 3 |

Here you can clearly see that data is sorted/group by City but values are in descending order, plus only 2 major complain are selected. Can you please help on how to build this data/or plot a graph in pandas

I have tried few code where I can select the top 2 complain by city but unable to sort the city based on the values. Even when I sort the data based on values then I lose the group by. Below is the code I am currently using

```
df1 = df.groupby(['City','Complaint Type']).size().reset_index(name = 'size')   
df2 = df1.sort_values(by = ['City', 'size'], ascending = [True, False]).groupby('City').head(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the dataframe the way you want, you need to first get the top 3 cities. To do this, you can sort and then call `unique()` on city column. Then sort the dataframe by these 3 cities (using `sort_value`) and get the top 2 complaints (using `groupby` and `head()`). This will give you the top 6 rows. If you want them grouped by city, you can use `pd.categorical()` on the data. Finally plot the graph using seaborn catplot. Code is below.

```
#Get top 3 cities in a list
top3=df.sort_values(by ='Value', ascending = False)['City'].unique()[0:3]
print(top3)

#Filter by these cities and pick top2 entries
df1=df[df['City'].isin(top3)].sort_values('Value', ascending = False).groupby('City').head(2)

#If you want the data grouped by city, then use categorical ordering
df1['City'] = pd.Categorical(df1['City'], top3)
df1.sort_values('City', inplace=True)
print(df1)

#Finally plot your graph
sns.catplot(data=df1, kind='bar', x='Complaint Type', y='Value', hue='City')
```

Note that you can exchange x and hue if you want to plot by each city in X axis

**Outputs**

*top3*

['ASTORIA' 'BAYSIDE' 'BELLEROSE']

*df1*

```
         City    Complaint Type  Value
6     ASTORIA  Blocked Driveway   3436
7     ASTORIA  Derelict Vehicle    426
9     BAYSIDE  Blocked Driveway    514
10    BAYSIDE  Derelict Vehicle    231
14  BELLEROSE  Blocked Driveway    138
15  BELLEROSE  Derelict Vehicle    120
```

**Plot**

[image]